# Getting "access forbidden by rule" error at magento in nginx server /app/etc/local.xml

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento-1.9

I am getting this error for my website which is built on magento-1.9.0.

```
2015/07/13 05:50:44 [error] 1371#0: *491517 access forbidden by rule, client: **.***.***.***, server: www.example.com, request: "POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

For your information: the IP address is always my own server. This only happens whenever I try to edit or update any item of "Shopping Cart Price Rules". There was a magento bug of shopping cart price rule and I have used a extension which is mentioned here https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix . That extension works perfectly in my local environment however it is also not working in live. I guess this error is preventing that extension to work perfectly. My live server is running on nginx.

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74146/getting-access-forbidden-by-rule-error-at-magento-in-nginx-server-app-etc-loc?noredirect=1#comment98149_74146 .

To sum up, Magento tries to access app/etc/local.xml via HTTP which fails, so you get this error log. And the point is, that it should fail! Otherwise everybody could see your database credentials.